# WP_Query() load selected post

Tags: php, posts, wp-query

I need to load a selected post in a ajax function, I have some problems writing the appropriate query that calls the post i'm pointing

```
 <?php
  $pb_id = $_POST['post_id'];
  $pb_details_args = array(
  'p' => $pb_id,
  );

 $pb_details_query = new WP_Query( $pb_details_args );

 while ($pb_details_query -> have_post() ):
 $pb_details_query -> the_post();
 echo '<h4>' . get_the_title() . '</h4>';
 endwhile
 ?>
```

at the moment i have this piece of code but i think is basically entirely wrong

The page where i need to laod this is http://www.nicolabertelloni.it/homus-wp/ in the box over the footer. you can see the entire code at https://github.com/wanbinkimoon/homus-web.git the code i'm referring is in homus-web/wp-content/themes/homus-theme/single_pb_post_details.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a query if you the know the post ID:

```
<?php

$post_id = absint( $_POST['post_id'] );

if ( ! $post = get_post( $post_id ) )
    exit; // Error

if ( $post->post_status !== 'publish' )
    exit; // Might want to prevent script kiddies from accessing private content

echo '<h4>' . get_the_title( $post ) . '</h4>';
```

Comment: my problem is with the query becuse i don't know the post id, the post id change based on the click of the user

Comment: But you *do* know the post ID, it's in your original code.

Comment: The post ID gets sent in the AJAX request when a user clicks, no?